# Effect of installing .NET 4.6 in the build server with existing .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web, migration

I'm in the situation where I need to install .NET 4.6 in the build server with running web apps targeted to .NET 4.0. Our new web app is targeted to .NET 4.6 so we need to install this version in the build server. But we are worried if this will have a negative effect with the existing application in the server. Note that we're not actually upgrading/migrating those existing applications to .NET 4.6. We just need to install 4.6 so that the newly web app will work in the build server.

We don't want to use 4.0 in our new web application anymore. We targeted to use at least 4.6 version of .NET for our succeeding projects. Any inputs will very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply installing a newer version of .Net on your server shouldn't affect the applications running on it. Those applications will still use the version of .Net they are targeted for, before using other versions of .Net. If you want more control over which framework version your app uses, you can use `<supportedRuntime>` elements in an app config file to explicitly state which runtimes your app supports.

If you are worried about the possible negative effects of switching your framework version, you can find framework changes between versions and their possible effects [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/)

Comment: Thanks Ben! All works in our build server as expected!